# spring boot actuator giving forbidden error when run on a different port other than application port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

=

Getting forbidden error while accessing actuator running on different port other than application port using custom spring security configuration.

```
application.properties file

management.security.enabled=false
management.context-path=/manage
management.port=8085

server.context-path=/lnhcverifyhcp
server.port=8090
```

spring boot version - 1.3.3.RELEASE

Getting forbidden error on accessing actuator url's

Comment: You've said that you're using custom Spring Security configuration, but have provided no details. There's a fair chance that that is where the problem lies

Comment: I have used custom configuration
but i have by-passed the security validation for actuator

 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/manafe/info").permitAll();

It works fine with if run on same port as that of server port but if run
on different port getting forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, my mcAfee using that port. Actually 403 is from McAfee.
hit this url and see what you get - http://localhost:8081/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using Spring Security with Spring Actuator. So, the configuration to escape the Actuator out the Security are:

```
endpoints:
  health: 
    sensitive:  false

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

You can disable security on the management port by adding this to your application.properties file:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Or, set your own username and password:

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html